# How to know when image uploading is finished?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, blockui

I want to use blockUI plugin for my project. I want to block UI during the uploading images, but i use simple image upload component (non ajax). Does any kind to identify when uploading images is finished and unbock UI?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, when you are not using AJAX, then the image upload does a POST to the server (i.e., entire page will reload). Then, you can run the blockUI JavaScript before submitting the form (in the form's onSubmit event) and the page will be unblocked the response is back.